How good are LLMs to fix typos?
I read:

As for fixing typos, ChatGPT not designed for this so it would most likely change the meaning even if you tell it otherwise. So that is not a way to avoid the blanket ban. The main issue is with "generate text" - I want to believe Grammarly are honest enough to leave only typo fixing tools, even AI powered, that really won't change meaning i.e. won't generate their own text, hence giving it the benefit of the doubt. Shadow Wizard Commented 2 hours ago 

This makes me wonder: How good are LLMs to fix typos?
I'm looking for studies, not some anecdotal evidence.

Here's a relevant study on grammar and spelling correction using a dataset written by native Brazilian Portuguese speakers. In particular, the dataset includes the following kinds of errors:

Spelling — 100 sentences with spelling, punctuation, or
accentuation errors.
Fast typing — 40 mistyped (e.g., when typing too fast)
sentences.

They compare GPT-3.5 and GPT-4 against MS Word & Google Docs. It seems like LLMs are strong typo correction tools (Table 3 from the paper):

Another relevant study on English and Russian can be found here.
The results for English (Table 10):

The results for Russian (Table 11):

Some of these datasets aren't strictly typo correction, but rather spelling correction, but it could nonetheless give some insight as it's a closely related task.

This paper looked at the abilility of LLMs to unscramble texts:
Unnatural Error Correction: GPT-4 Can Almost Perfectly Handle Unnatural Scrambled Text. Qi Cao, Takeshi Kojima, Yutaka Matsuo, Yusuke Iwasawa. EMNLP 2023.
Task:

(1) Scrambled Sentence Recovery (ScrRec). In this task, we provide a sentence containing scrambled words to LLMs and then ask them to recover original sentence from it. This task can be utilized to directly measure the capability of LLMs to recognize and reconstruct the scrambled words in a sentence.


Results (just look at the left plot; the right plot is another task):



